# Non-EU National Visiting the UK with a Long-term Residence Permit Issued by a Schengen State

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, italy, sri-lankan-citizens

Sri Lankan National working in Italy for several years. Has two-year renewable residency permit.
Can she visit UK?

Answer (score 1):

No. United Kingdom is not part of the Schengen territory and thus even a permanent residence card from Italy (or any other Schengen state) will not allow a person to enter the UK without valid visa.

Note: There are exceptional cases where a non-EU citizen living in the Schengen territory with a valid residence permit 'may' be admitted to the UK without a valid visa. One such case that I know of is when the said non-EU person is a holder of a residence permit that has been issued as a result of being a family member of an EU citizen. (read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_card_of_a_family_member_of_a_Union_citizen#Implementation_in_the_United_Kingdom))

Comment: Rather than *no,* it would be more precise to say *not without a UK visa.*